# Rails 7.1.1 - spawning error occurred - passenger - You have already activated stringio 3.0.0, but your Gemfile requires stringio 3.0.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, passenger, ruby-on-rails-7

When upgrading to the latest version of rails, I'm experiencing the following error with passenger refusing to start.

`The application encountered the following error: You have already activated stringio 3.0.0, but your Gemfile requires stringio 3.0.8. Since stringio is a default gem, you can either remove your dependency on it or try updating to a newer version of bundler that supports stringio as a default gem. (Gem::LoadError)`

Looking up the version of gems installed, only `stringio (default: 3.0.0)` is defined.

and in my gemlock file we now have

`psych (5.1.1.1) stringio`
and

`stringio (3.0.8)`

One suggestion to this problem that my stack support team have suggested is to place gem 'stringio', '3.0.0' in the gemfile and force it to use this version.

This doesn't feel right to me and is somthing that I've never had to do before

Questions:

- Can anyone provide advice on if the above solution is the correct thing to do?
- Can anyone help point me in the right direction as to another fix to solve this issue and where I should be looking?

Comment: What version of Bundler do you use (`bundler -v`)? Did you try to update bundler (`gem update bundler`) as suggested in the error message?

Comment: Using the latest version already - v2.4.21

Comment: What command do you run? Do you run it with `bundle exec` like this `bundle exec rails start`?

Comment: Do you have psych set in your gemfile?  If so, remove it and try to `bundle install`

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue, in Rails 7.1 they added `irb` as dependency to `railties` in order to get "the latest version". This causes a cascade of dependencies to be required: `rdoc`, `psych`, `stringio` which in turn cause various installation issues (`psych` require libyaml, `stringio` conflicts with the default version)... I'm still fighting this but it's starting to get annoying.

Answer (score 4):

The proper solution is to add `passenger_preload_bundler on;` to your NGINX config. Then you don't have to use outdated gems.

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/docs/references/config_reference/nginx/#passenger_preload_bundler

[Source from reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/18105z2/comment/kab6wfa/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and tried everything I could think of... Rebuilding Passenger Docker, updating bundler, manually removing the `stringio` gem (which isn't permitted because it's a default gem).

The only solution that I came up with that actually worked is updating my project's `Gemfile` to explicitly require the version of `stringio` that Passenger Docker is using by default.

For me, that meant editing ./Gemfile to add:

```
gem "stringio", "3.0.1"
```

I agree with you that it feels like a very low quality workaround that will likely create more maintenance overhead in the future.